# Expansion of $e^{-\sqrt{\tan(x)/(\pi/2-x)}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> I am trying to find an equivalent of : 
>   $$e^{-\sqrt{\tan(x)/(\pi/2-x)}}$$ at $x = \pi /2$.

I am sure I need to do an asymptotic expansion of the terms involved but I am not getting anywhere.

For example using the fact that:  $e^x = 1 + x + o(x^2)$  at $x=0$

I get that : 
$$e^{-\sqrt{\tan(x)/(\pi/2-x)}} = 1 -\sqrt{\tan(x)/(\pi/2-x)} +o(-\sqrt{\tan(x)/(\pi/2-x)})$$
Now I don't know what to do? Should I expand each term and then take the "biggest" one in order to get an equivalent ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After letting $t=\pi/2-x$,
$$\lim_{x\to \pi/2^-}\tan(x)\cdot (\pi/2-x)=\lim_{t\to 0^+}\tan(\pi/2-t)\cdot t=\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{t}{\tan(t)}=1$$
which implies that, as $x\to \pi/2^-$,
$$\sqrt{\tan(x)/(\pi/2-x)}\sim \frac{1}{\pi/2-x}.$$
Note that the expansion of $e^x$ at $0$ is not useful at this point since the exponent $-\sqrt{\tan(x)/(\pi/2-x)}$ goes to $-\infty$ as $x\to \pi/2^-$.

For a more general expansion consider for $t=\pi/2-x\to 0^+$,
\begin{align}e^{-\sqrt{\tan(x)/(\pi/2-x)}}&=e^{-1/t}
\exp\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{t\tan(t)}}+\frac{1}{t}\right)\\
&=e^{-1/t}
\exp\left(-\frac{1}{t\sqrt{1+t^2/3+O(t^4)}}+\frac{1}{t}\right)\\
&=e^{-1/t}
\exp\left(\frac{t}{6}+O(t^3)\right)=e^{-1/t}
\left(1+\frac{t}{6}+\frac{t^2}{72}+O(t^3)\right)\end{align}
where we need $\tan(t)=t+t^3/3+O(t^5)$.

Comment: @YuriyS It looks ok. The  $1$ comes after considering the exponential. Am I missing something?

Comment: Robert Z, sorry, it was my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Considering
$$z=e^{-\sqrt{\frac{\tan (x)}{\frac{\pi }{2}-x}}}$$ let $x=\frac \pi 2-y$ to make
$$z=e^{-\sqrt{\frac{\cot (y)}{y}}}\implies \log(z)=-\sqrt{\frac{\cot (y)}{y}}$$ Now, using Taylor expansion
$$\log(z)=-\frac{1}{y}+\frac{y}{6}+O\left(y^3\right)$$ So, for small $y$
$$z\sim e^{-\frac 1 y}$$